# How to use pseudocode (listing) in Beamer article mode?

Tags: beamer, listings, pseudocode, beamerarticle

I am trying to generate pseudocode in both presentation slides and handout using `beamer`.

I can use the `listings` package in the slides by adding `[fragile]` to the `frame` environment. However, how can I use the `lstlistings` environment when in article mode? Below is a minimal example.

File: `slides.tex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{mwe-body.tex}
```

File: `notes.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\input{mwe-body.tex}
```

File: `mwe-body.tex`

```
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Frame 1}
  test 1
  \begin{lstlisting}
    int sum = 0;
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\mode<article>{
  test 2

  \begin{lstlisting}
    int sum = 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
}
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex slides.tex` works to generate the presentation.

`pdflatex notes.tex` has the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
<to be read again>
               \par
l.18 }
```

Any solutions?  Note, this is cross-posted to [Stack-Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540237/pseudocode-listings-in-beamer-article-mode), but may get more responses here :)

Comment: Have you tried avoiding `\mode<article>` entirely and using `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}` in the presentation wrapper file? Then, anything you want just in the article can go outside a frame.

Comment: Yes, this works in both the minimal example and my original project!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mike Renfro,

> Have you tried avoiding \mode entirely and using
>   \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer} in the presentation wrapper
>   file? Then, anything you want just in the article can go outside a
>   frame.